# How to hide and show element based on breakpoint?

Tags: tailwind-css

You would assume that this div would be `hidden` unless viewport is `md` or larger.

```
<div class="hidden md:inline-block"></div>
```

But in reality it's always hidden regardless of viewport.

How can I hide this div unless viewport > md?

Comment: It seems to be working fine: https://play.tailwindcss.com/6A9iTibEwa Something else is your problem's source because you understood and implemented the breakpoints correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working as expected !

```
<div class="hidden md:inline-block text-4xl"> Hello there </div>
```

Output in `viewport > 768px:`

[image]

Output in `viewport < 768px:`

[image]

Note:

According to docs `md:`  has minimum width of `768px` , which you can customize further according to your needs in `config file`

> md:   768px   @media (min-width: 768px) { ... }

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this.
`div className="invisible lg:visible">`
so the div is only visible from 1024px (based on Tailwind's responsive sizing).
For your situation it will be
`<div class="invisible lg:visible md:inline-block"></div>`